# Make <g> tag to support overflow-x: scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a ng-bootsrap chart that I need to be scrollable in smaller screen sizes.
The container of the wanted element to be scrolled is a "g" tag inside "svg" tag.
I cannot make this to work even if I try to put a style="overflow-x: scroll" programmatically.

```
<svg class="ngx-charts" width="1173" height="300">
   <defs>...</defs>
   <g class="bubble chart" transform="translate(200,10)">
      <g ngx-chart-x-axis style="overflow-x: scroll"> <---- NOT WORKING
         ...
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try adding a specific `height`

Comment: Didn't work either

Comment: If you want `overflow-x` you must set **`width`**   (`height` is to `overflow-y`)

Comment: Don't think `<g>` tag support scrolling at all. But not sure. You always can surround the whole `svg` with `div` and set scrolling there.

Comment: Thats not possible because the svg tag is not where i want the scroll but on a specific g tag